# Compiled with warnings. React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

**Hello, pleases help, i use react-create-app and i have warnings:**

```
C:/Users/Vitaliy/Documents/GitHub/ProShop/frontend/node_modules/process/browser.js
[1] There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
[1] This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
[1] Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
[1] * C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\process\browser.js
[1]     Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
[1]     C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\react-error-overlay\lib\index.js  
[1] * C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\proshop\frontend\node_modules\process\browser.js
[1]     Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
[1]     C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\proshop\frontend\node_modules\axios\lib\defaults.js
[1]
[1] (webpack)/buildin/global.js
[1] There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
[1] This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
[1] Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
[1] * C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
[1]     Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
[1]     C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\node-libs-browser\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js
[1] * C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\proshop\frontend\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
[1]     Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
[1]     C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\proshop\frontend\node_modules\symbol-observable\es\index.js
```

what I can do with it?

Comment: how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

In the warning it says:
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casin, and is true.

```
C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\**ProShop**\frontend\node_modules\process\browser.js

C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\ProShop\frontend\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!C:\Users\Vitaliy\Documents\GitHub\**proshop**\frontend\node_modules\process\browser.js
```

At the end of this routes I see "ProShop" and "proshop", solve that and the warning will disappear.

Comment: thank you very much! 
I starting npm run dev in .../proshop/...
but need starting in .../ProShop/...

amazing)